# How to pass the keyword for another funtion's argument within a new decorator?

Tags: python, function, flask, arguments, keyword

```
def machines(machine_name):  
  rb = np.array(machines_file.loc[machines_file['Machine'].str.contains(machine_name), 'Resolved By'])
  rb_o = np.count_nonzero(rb == 'Outsource')
  rb_ih = np.count_nonzero(rb == 'In-House')
  return render_template('reachtruck.html',outsource=rb_o, inhouse=rb_ih)

#Passing a keyword for the argument of above funtion
@app.route('/home/reach_truck')
machines('Reach Truck')
```

The code is showing error of indentation when I am passing the keyword under the flask decorator

Answer (score 1):

The decorator goes on the function definition, not the function call:

```
@app.route('/home/reach_truck')
def machines(machine_name):  
    rb = np.array(machines_file.loc[machines_file['Machine'].str.contains(machine_name), 'Resolved By'])
    rb_o = np.count_nonzero(rb == 'Outsource')
    rb_ih = np.count_nonzero(rb == 'In-House')
    return render_template('reachtruck.html',outsource=rb_o, inhouse=rb_ih)

machines('Reach Truck')
```

If you want to only apply the decorator to that specific invocation of the function, don't use the decorator syntax, just call it as a normal function (note: I'm not a Flask expert but I don't think `app.route` will work as intended if you call it this way):

```
app.route('/home/reach_truck')(machines)('Reach Truck')
```

Comment: The situation is that I have to pass multiple keywords for same function with different URLs that's why I can't put the decorator above the function.

Comment: @RohaanSheikh Sounds like you should use variable rules in the route instead.

Answer (score 1):

decorator is basically a function. Just pass to it

```
app.route('/home/reach_truck')(machines)('Reach Truck')
```

Comment: Misplaced parens.  The argument to the function returned by `app.route()` needs to be the function you want to decorate; that in turn will produce the decorated function.

Comment: you were correct, nice catch